# Función para desencadenar un JSON en PL/SQL

Tags: json, plsql

Me podrían ayudar con una orientación para formular o crear una función en `PL/SQL` que me desencadene un `JSON` que viene de la siguiente manera Ej:

> {Estado:ERROR,Id:0,Mensaje:Existe un caso abierto para la victima, con
>   la misma tipificación (Proceso, Solicitud y Condición). No se puede
>   crear el caso.}

La idea es sacar las cadenas que se encuentran delante de los dos puntos **":"**,
he creado una consulta que lo hace, pero me gustaría implementarlo en una función. Soy nuevo en el mundo del lenguaje PL.

```
 SELECT substr('{Estado:ERROR MASIVO,Id:0,Mensaje:Existe un caso abierto para la victima}',
        INSTR('{Estado:ERROR MASIVO,Id:0,Mensaje:Existe un caso abierto para la victima}','Estado:')+7, ---> Trae la cadena que esta despues de 'Estado:'
        instr(substr('{Estado:ERROR MASIVO,Id:0,Mensaje:Existe un caso abierto para la victima}',
         INSTR('{Estado:ERROR MASIVO,Id:0,Mensaje:Existe un caso abierto para la victima}','Estado:')+7),'Id:')-2
              ) ESTADO,

   substr('{Estado:ERROR MASIVO,Id:0,Mensaje:Existe un caso abierto para la victima}',
    INSTR('{Estado:ERROR MASIVO,Id:0,Mensaje:Existe un caso abierto para la victima}','Id:')+3,
    instr(substr('{Estado:ERROR MASIVO,Id:0,Mensaje:Existe un caso abierto para la victima}',
     INSTR('{Estado:ERROR MASIVO,Id:0,Mensaje:Existe un caso abierto para la victima}','Id:')+3),'Mensaje:')-2
          ) ID,
    REPLACE(substr('{Estado:ERROR MASIVO,Id:0,Mensaje:Existe un caso abierto para la victima}',
    INSTR('{Estado:ERROR MASIVO,Id:0,Mensaje:Existe un caso abierto para la victima}','Mensaje:')+8
    ),'}','') mensaje           


FROM  dual;
```

Gracias.

Comment: En cuál versión de Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con la API [APEX_JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_json.htm#AEAPI29646), ejemplo:

```
DECLARE
    s varchar2(32767) := '{"Estado":"ERROR","Id":"0","Mensaje":"Existe un caso abierto para la victima, 
                           con la misma tipificación (Proceso, Solicitud y Condición). 
                           No se puede crear el caso."}';
BEGIN
    apex_json.parse(s);
    sys.dbms_output.put_line('Mensaje: ' || apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'Mensaje'));
END;
```

Comment: Es posible usar apex_json.parse en 11g?